# Is it okay to host sitemap.xml outside the domain root?

Tags: seo, sitemap

Let's say I have a website `www.example.com`.  Is it okay to host the sitemap.xml **outside** `www.example.com` such as `https://example.cloudstorage.com/static/sitemap.xml`?  All the entries in the sitemap will have absolute URLs such as `https://www.example.com/path/to/page`.

The reason is that I will have an automated process to update my website's sitemap.xml but the process cannot cannot access files within `www.example.com` directly.

Will a search engine like Google or Bing allow for sitemap.xml to be hosted outside the website being indexed?

If yes, is there a SEO penalty for doing this?

Comment: Sitemaps have almost nothing to do with SEO.   They can the search engine crawlers to come crawl pages on your site, but have little influence on decisions about which pages get indexed or how well those pages get ranked.   See  [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for referring me to that post.  So it looks like search engine uses sitemap for supplementary information.  My website's sitemap is autogenerated, I just want to know whether hosting it outside the domain is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Google and Bing not allows your submit the external XML sitemap(not the same domain), your XML sitemap file should be access on the same domain.

you have many solutions to solve if you host sitemap on the outside of site.

1. Add reverse-proxy on Nginx to access outside sitemap file.

```
 example.com/sitemap > abc.example/sitemap.xml
```

2. Uses third-party tools that supports custom domain for your sitemap. like https://sitemaphub.com

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a sitemap-index it looks like you can point to a domain other than the one you are using for your site - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/large-sitemaps